# git see commit count difference between two arbitrary branches

Tags: git

If my local is tracking `origin/master` and I run `git status`, I get a very useful message telling me:

```
Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
   and have 7 and 11 different commits each, respectively.
   (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
```

Is it possible to get the same information against an *arbitrary* branch and not the remote branch that I'm tracking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, just create a little advanced alias:

```
$ git config alias.branch-diff '!branch_diff() { [ $# -ne 2 ] && echo '\''error: branch-diff needs exactly two arguments'\'' >&2 && exit 1; echo -e "'\''$1'\'' and '\''$2'\'' have diverged,\n   and have $(git log --oneline $2..$1 | wc -l) and $(git log --oneline $1..$2 | wc -l) different commits each, respectively."; }; branch_diff'
$ git branch-diff 8.1.0
error: branch-diff needs exactly two arguments
$ git branch-diff 8.1.0 8.1.1
'8.1.0' and '8.1.1' have diverged,
   and have 800 and 4122 different commits each, respectively.
```

Answer (score 2):

The following will show you the commits that exist on `[other branch]` and not your own.

`git log HEAD..[other branch]`

Combine that with a few other switches/CLI tools and you can get similar info, e.g.:

`git log HEAD..origin/whatever --oneline | wc -l`

...will show you how many commits exist on `origin/whatever` that don't exist on your branch. If you were to swap `HEAD` and `origin/whatever`, you'd see how many commits exist on your branch and not on the other